# FLOW3 action parameters and arrays of objects

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, typo3-flow

[FLOW3](http://flow3.typo3.org/) provides a convenient way to pass entities by ID in the URL, and get them automatically instantiated in the controller action's parameters:

```
class PostController extends \TYPO3\FLOW3\MVC\Controller\ActionController {
    public function editAction(Post $post) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But what about the use case where you have checkboxes, each representing a particular object? It would be handy to get them autoinstantiated as well:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="2" />
...
```

Is there a way to tell FLOW3 to auto-instantiate the `$tags` variable as an array of `Tag` objects? Something like:

```
public function setTagsAction(Post $post, /** @var Model\Tag */ array $tags) {
    $post->setTags($tags);
}
```

Comment: Now beta, report the missing feature (or faulty implementation) ;)

Comment: I'd like to be sure that it's not already possible, before writing a feature request :)

Comment: try `<input type="checkbox" name="tags[][__identity]" value="1" />` (at least in extbase this should be possible)

Comment: Have you tried a DTO?

Comment: @colares How would a DTO help here?

Comment: Oh, nevermind about about DTO! hehe `Post` hasMany `Tag`, right? So you don't need to set a new parameter, all you need to do is to send and get tags as `Post`'s children. Note: there is a trick thing you MUST to do at `initializeMyActionNameAction`. Are you using Flow 2.0 (they just released 2.1 today) and FLUID? I can post a complete answer.

Comment: That's not the point: I want(ed) (this question is more than 2 years old) to auto-instantiate Tags that were **not** already on Post, but whose IDs were posted in a form. If you have a way to do that with any version of Flow, you're welcome to post an answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * @param Post $post
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection<\your\namespace\Model\Tag> $tag
 */

public function setTagsAction(Post $post, $tags) { ...
```

afaik Doctrine will convert your array to a Collection Holding Objects mapped by the provided array

Answer (score 0):

remove the word array before $tags

Comment: And how do you specify the class name? Did you try it?